# Rails: secondary layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I started my first *serious* rails app. I'm building a site which will need for a specific model another structure as the application.html.erb.
I'd like to have a general layout or structure as application.html.erb but for my, lets say, articles model, and then `=yield` any view of that model there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keyword `layout` to override the default layout conventions in your controllers.

following your example:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'articles_layout'
  ...
end
```

Comment: How always too easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the section about Nested Layouts within the Layouts and Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).

Comment: I have read about nested layouts, but I don't want to nest them. Thank you anyway, @Hélio's answer solves it.